# Localize SharePoint 2010 Folder Names

Tags: sharepoint, localization, sharepoint-2010

I'm looking for a way to localize SharePoint 2010 Folder Names, for a specific application.

I've seen that site names/description are automatically translated, and it seems like SharePoint 2010 supports "multilingual" fields for metadata - but I haven't been able to apply this successfully for folder names.

The folders are automatically generated, and the number of folder is limited (so I'm not looking at providing the users a way to translate their folder names, but a way to localize a predefined folder structure).

In a nutshell :
- is there a way to localize folder names ?
- if yes, is what's the best way to deploy this as part of a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered how Managed Metadata might be able to help you with this? If you're able to control terms that are also localized in Taxonomy, perhaps when creating a folder you would pull from the Managed Metadata Store, and then display the appropriate language based on the user's language setting. Just a thought... Since you know the name of the folder ahead of time, you could use that as a label for a folder name term, and then pull another label that matches the user's language and display that.

Answer (score 0):

You can start using a resource files in your project and this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnwpowell/archive/2009/11/29/sharepoint-2010-localization-with-visual-studio-2010.aspx) can help you about it.

But if you want to let the user, who creates a folder to set its localized name; then you should consider using SP event receivers.

I hope I've understood you correctly.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer - can you actually set a localizedName to a folderName ? I figured how to do it on Content Types and Columns Names, but not on folder names (and I'd like to do it in a way that translate well through other access protocols like webDAV, etc....). - FWIW, the folders themselves are created programatically, so I can manipulate their names easily (I currently don't have the tranlations in a resx file, but I could probably generate one based on the user entered configuration values)

Comment: I don't know if there is a way through interface of SP, but surely you can set the folders' names programmatically in logic needed by your localization aim.